# Avoiding need to specify using operator=

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

I'm attempting to create a base class for creating helpers around various scoped operations, and to do so the base class allows the assignment of a callable. A simple predicate determines whether or not the callable is invoked. Regardless, the dtor is always invoked.

The catch is that each derived class needs to explicitly inherit the operator=. Is there a way to write the base class so that this is not required?

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using callback_t = std::function<void(void)>;

struct C
{
    constexpr C(bool ok) : ok_{ok} {}
    bool ok_ {false};

    bool operator=(callback_t fn) const noexcept {
        return ok_ ? fn(), true : false;
    }

    ~C() noexcept {
        std::cout << "end\n";
    }
};

struct D final : public C
{
    using C::operator=;
};

int main()
{
    auto predicate = [] { return true; };

    D{predicate()} = [] {
        std::cout << "ok\n";
    };
    D{false} = [] {
        std::cout << "wrong\n";
    };
}
```

(also https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/eh8ncffos)

Removing the line from `struct D`

```
    using C::operator=;
```

causes compile errors since `D`s default copy-operator preempts C's custom operator=.

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:24:9: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'D' and 'main()::<lambda()>')
24 |         };
    |         ^
<source>:14:12: note: candidate: 'constexpr D& D::operator=(const D&)'
14 |     struct D final : public C
    |            ^
<source>:14:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'main()::<lambda()>' to 'const D&'
<source>:14:12: note: candidate: 'constexpr D& D::operator=(D&&)'
<source>:14:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'main()::<lambda()>' to 'D&&'
<source>:27:9: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'D' and 'main()::<lambda()>')
27 |         };
    |         ^
<source>:14:12: note: candidate: 'constexpr D& D::operator=(const D&)'
14 |     struct D final : public C
    |            ^
<source>:14:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'main()::<lambda()>' to 'const D&'
<source>:14:12: note: candidate: 'constexpr D& D::operator=(D&&)'
<source>:14:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'main()::<lambda()>' to 'D&&'
```

Comment: Try using CRTP?

Comment: @IgorR. That's what I'd do if it was just the default operator=, but this is a conversion operator, and I can't seem to get that to happen with crtp: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/neKGzK8oa

Comment: Do you have to spell it `operator=`? As opposed to like... `call`?

Comment: @Barry Blame boost/ut; tldr we didn't want to have to add parens around lambdas being passed to it. It's being used as a sort of generic scope-wrapper/defer mechanism: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/E8hhrxhd3

Comment: @Barry (I prefer 'operator&&' given the conditional execution, but I'd still like to know it could be achieved with operator= without needing the 'using' term)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The catch is that each derived class needs to explicitly inherit the `operator=`. Is there a way to write the base class so that this is not required?

No, this isn't possible.

The rule is that functions in different scopes do not overload. Since the derived class will always have something named `operator=` (either the derived class declares one itself, or the copy assignment operator is declared implicitly... even if it would be defined as deleted). So when you do `derived = x;`, name lookup for `operator=` will start in `Derived` and, having found candidates, stop there. It won't keep going to look into the base class... unless you bring in that candidate with a *using-declaration* like you demonstrated the question.

The only way to still use `operator=` but stash the functionality somewhere would be to actually invert your class hierarchy. Instead of:

```cpp
struct C {
    // ... implementation here ...
};

struct D : C {
    using C::operator=;
};

// use D
```

you can do:

```cpp
template <typename Derived>
struct C {
    // implementation here
};

struct D { }

// use C<D>
```

This way, `C` is actually the class you're interacting with, so its `operator=` would be the first candidate considered.

---

Alternatively, if you simply don't use `=` as the spelling for this operation, every other operator is available and they would not need a *using-declaration* in the derived class to work.

Given [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67527019/avoiding-need-to-specify-using-operator?noredirect=1#comment119357082_67527019) about wishing to avoid parentheses, your list of binary operators that would not require one are: `->*`, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `^`, `&`, `|`, `&&`, `||`, `<`, `>`, `<<`, and `>>` (plus the compound-assignment versions of those).

I'm deliberately excluding `==` and `<=>` from the list because those are special and just don't.